# Unit testing with mvc api & ninject

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, ninject

Sorry if this comes across as a stupid question im just not sure how to get started writing some unit tests.

I have a solution containing an api and a unit test project. The api has a repository/interface used for data access using ninject.

My question is how is my best way to unit test my api controllers. I have read a little about Moq but not sure if I need to use it as I want to test against my database.

I have read that I need to use a `[TestInitialize]` attribute

```
[TestInitialize]
public void MyTestInitialize()
{
  var kernel = NinjectWebCommon.CreatePublicKernel();
  kernel.Bind<BusinessController>().ToSelf();
}
```

My problem is my test project cant resolve CreatePublicKernel 
Checking the NinjectWebCommon class in the api there is no function called CreatePublicKernel.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ninject (or other DI library) is used only to provide dependencies into your controller's constructor. E.g. if you need `BusinessController` which requires two repositories, then controller should have constructor which expects these dependencies:

```
public BusinessController(IUserRepository userRepository, 
                          IOrderRepository orderRepository)
{
    _userRepository = userRepository;
    _orderRepository = orderRepository;
}
```

If you want to write **unit tests** for your controller, you should provide mocked implementations of these repositories. Use `Moq` or other framework for creating mocks:

```
var userRepositoryMock = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
var orderRepositoryMock = new Mock<IOrderRepository>();
// setup mocks here
var controller = new BusinessController(userRepositoryMock.Object,
                                        orderRepositoryMock.Object);
```

If you are writing **integration tests** for your controller, you should provide real implementations of these repositories, which use some real database.

```
var userRepository = new NHibernateUserRepository();
var orderRepository = new NHibernateOrderRepository();
// prepare some data in database here
var controller = new BusinessController(userRepository, orderRepository);
```

You can move controller instantiation into some method which is executed before each test (SetUp or TestInitialize method) in order to remove code duplication from your tests.

---

UPDATE: You also can use Ninject for integration testing. Just create Ninject module which will be used both by your real application and integration tests:

```
public class FooModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUserRepository>().To<NHibernateUserRepository>();
        Bind<IOrderRepository>().To<NHibernateOrderRepository>();
        Bind<BusinessController>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

Then use this module both to create kernel in NinjectWebCommon.CreateKernel method and kernel in your tests:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new FooModule());
var controller = kernel.Get<ValuesController>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your really helpful answer. That makes things a whole lot clearer now